# How to convert number format of a calculated column to time (hh:mm:ss) format, sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, formatting, julian-date

First I'm sorry for the poor English but I'll try to be as understandable as possible.

I'm trying to make a Oracle Database SQL Query which subtracts the datetime value of two existing columns, I managed how to do it using the instruction shown below but the column TEMPO that I created is returning with NUMBER format.

```
SELECT M.NUMOS, M.CODFUNCOS, M.DTINICIOOS, M.DTFIMSEPARACAO,
M.DTFIMSEPARACAO - M.DTINICIOOS AS TEMPO 
FROM PCMOVENDPEND M
WHERE DTFIMSEPARACAO IS NOT NULL
AND DATA >= SYSDATE-1
```

The Output is at it goes.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTqfS.png)

I need to convert the column TEMPO format to TIME as 'hh:mm:ss', and if some results passes through 24 hours it keeps adding like 32:01:20 (just like the [hh]:mm:ss Excel formatting).

I tried a few things like the instruction below but it returns **ORA-00932 error inconsistent data type, expected TIME and returned DATE JULIAN** (I don't know if it is the exact error description, my DBX is in Portuguese), unfortunately I can't do any changes to the root tables if it would help.

```
SELECT M.NUMOS, M.CODFUNCOS, M.DTINICIOOS, M.DTFIMSEPARACAO,
CAST(M.DTFIMSEPARACAO - M.DTINICIOOS AS TIME) AS TEMPO 
FROM PCMOVENDPEND M
WHERE DTFIMSEPARACAO IS NOT NULL
AND DATA >= SYSDATE-1
```

Anyways, it is so important that the column TEMPO format is TIME because I'll use the sql query as an instruction to PowerBi Direct Query and I can't import the database to work it with PowerQuery since it is too large data.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can please provide sample data of M.DTFIMSEPARACAO, M.DTINICIOOS columns?

Comment: Sure https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTqfS.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function makes it prettier. It returns *number of days* formatted as `dd:hh:mi:ss`.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_days2ddhhmiss (par_broj_dana in number)
  2     return varchar2
  3  is
  4     l_broj_dana  number := par_broj_dana;
  5     retval       varchar2 (20);
  6  begin
  7     with podaci
  8          as (select trunc (l_broj_dana) broj_dana,
  9                     round (mod (l_broj_dana * 24, 24), 2) broj_sati,
 10                     round (mod (l_broj_dana * 24 * 60, 60), 2) broj_minuta,
 11                     round (mod (l_broj_dana * 24 * 60 * 60, 60), 2)
 12                        broj_sekundi
 13                from dual)
 14     select    lpad (p.broj_dana, 2, '0')
 15            || ':'
 16            || lpad (trunc (p.broj_sati), 2, '0')
 17            || ':'
 18            || lpad (trunc (p.broj_minuta), 2, '0')
 19            || ':'
 20            || lpad (trunc (p.broj_sekundi), 2, '0')
 21       into retval
 22       from podaci p;
 23
 24     return retval;
 25  end f_days2ddhhmiss;
 26  /

Function created.
```

Example:

Without it, you get decimal number:

```
SQL> select to_date('07.08.2020 14:25', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  2       - to_date('03.08.2020 13:20', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') result
  3  from dual;

    RESULT
----------
4,04513889
```

With it, you get what you wanted:

```
SQL> select f_days2ddhhmiss(to_date('07.08.2020 14:25', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  2                       - to_date('03.08.2020 13:20', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  3                        ) result
  4  from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
04:01:05:00

SQL>
```

---

Yes, such (or similar) code can be used directly in SQL, but it makes a `SELECT` statement kind of *ugly* and difficult to read.

Your query would then be

```
SELECT m.numos,
       m.codfuncos,
       m.dtinicioos,
       m.dtfimseparacao,
       f_days2ddhhmiss (m.dtfimseparacao - m.dtinicioos) AS tempo
  FROM pcmovendpend m
 WHERE     dtfimseparacao IS NOT NULL
       AND data >= SYSDATE - 1
```

See if it helps.

Comment: Sorry for being such a newbie, but any of those commands will make changes to the original database structure? If so I can get in some real trouble

Comment: Function will be created in that schema, yes. No data would be affected.

Comment: I didn't use directly your code to make it work but you gave me and idea how to do it.
Our oracle database already have a function to do what i wanted but that wasn't working as a SQL Instruction, so I got the function code and embedded to the select command and it worked!

Comment: OK, I'm glad if it helped.

Comment: Here's what I used.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WMS_CORINGA(TEMPO NUMBER)
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  HORA    NUMBER;
  MINUTO  NUMBER(2);
  SEGUNDO NUMBER(2);
  TEMPOABS NUMBER;
BEGIN
 IF TEMPO <> 0 THEN
   TEMPOABS := ABS(TEMPO);
    HORA := TRUNC(TEMPOABS*24);
    MINUTO := TRUNC(((TEMPOABS*24)-HORA) * 60);
    SEGUNDO := ((((TEMPOABS*24)-HORA) * 60) - MINUTO) * 60;
   
    RETURN TO_CHAR(HORA, 'FM9999900') || ':'|| TO_CHAR(MINUTO, 'FM00') || ':' || TO_CHAR (SEGUNDO, 'FM00');
 ELSE
 RETURN '';
 END IF;
END;

Answer (score 0):

With Littlefoots help I managed a way to convert the column to the desired format, just as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WMS_CORINGA(TEMPO NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
HORA NUMBER;
MINUTO NUMBER(2);
SEGUNDO NUMBER(2);
TEMPOABS NUMBER;
BEGIN
IF TEMPO <> 0 THEN
TEMPOABS := ABS(TEMPO);
HORA := TRUNC(TEMPOABS*24);
MINUTO := TRUNC(((TEMPOABS*24)-HORA) * 60);
SEGUNDO := ((((TEMPOABS*24)-HORA) * 60) - MINUTO) * 60;
RETURN TO_CHAR(HORA, 'FM9999900') || ':'|| TO_CHAR(MINUTO, 'FM00') || ':' || TO_CHAR (SEGUNDO, 'FM00');
ELSE
RETURN '';
END IF;
END;

SELECT  M.NUMOS, M.CODFUNCOS, M.DTINICIOOS, M.DTFIMSEPARACAO,
WMS_CORINGA(M.DTFIMSEPARACAO - M.DTINICIOOS) AS TEMPO_EM_SEPARACAO  
FROM PCMOVENDPEND M
WHERE DTFIMSEPARACAO IS NOT NULL
AND DATA>= SYSDATE-1
```

But I couldn't make the PowerBI connection, the output is **Details: "This native database query isn't currently supported."**

Anyways, learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast dates to timestamps before subtracting. The result of the subtraction is an [interval](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-dates-timestamps-and-intervals) represented as "days hh24:mi:ss.fff". If necessary you can then use the [extract](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/extract.php) function to pull out the individual components. That way you have neither an ugly query nor a a need to create a function.

```
with the_dates( dt1, dt2) as 
   ( select to_date('07.08.2020 14:25', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
          , to_date('03.08.2020 13:20', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')  
       from dual
   ) 
select dt1, dt2, cast(dt1 as timestamp) - cast(dt2 as timestamp) result
  from the_dates;
```