# Oracle/SQL Power Bi DirectQuery Instruction Error "This native database query isn't currently supported."

Tags: sql, oracle, function, connection, powerbi

First I would like to apologize for the poor English but I'll try to make myself as clear as possible.

I'm trying to make an SQL Instruction work as a shortcut with PowerBI since I had a lot of trouble trying to manipulate the information without importing the whole data (it's really big data) to build the measurements, but with the SQL Instruction as below the query ran pretty fast in PowerBI.

```
SELECT M.NUMOS, M.CODFUNCOS, M.DTINICIOOS, M.DTFIMSEPARACAO,
M.DTFIMSEPARACAO - M.DTINICIOOS AS TEMPO 
FROM PCMOVENDPEND M
WHERE DTFIMSEPARACAO IS NOT NULL
AND DATA >= SYSDATE-1
```

The only problem was the column TEMPO that had to have it's format changed from NUMBER to TIME so I could work it easily with PowerBI without importing the table to convert it with PowerQuery Editor, I got help [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63301655/how-to-convert-number-format-of-a-calculated-column-to-time-hhmmss-format-s) and managed to convert the column type with the code below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WMS_CORINGA(TEMPO NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
HORA NUMBER;
MINUTO NUMBER(2);
SEGUNDO NUMBER(2);
TEMPOABS NUMBER;
BEGIN
IF TEMPO <> 0 THEN
TEMPOABS := ABS(TEMPO);
HORA := TRUNC(TEMPOABS*24);
MINUTO := TRUNC(((TEMPOABS*24)-HORA) * 60);
SEGUNDO := ((((TEMPOABS*24)-HORA) * 60) - MINUTO) * 60;
RETURN TO_CHAR(HORA, 'FM9999900') || ':'|| TO_CHAR(MINUTO, 'FM00') || ':' || TO_CHAR (SEGUNDO, 'FM00');
ELSE
RETURN '';
END IF;
END;

SELECT  M.NUMOS, M.CODFUNCOS, M.DTINICIOOS, M.DTFIMSEPARACAO,
WMS_CORINGA(M.DTFIMSEPARACAO - M.DTINICIOOS) AS TEMPO_EM_SEPARACAO  
FROM PCMOVENDPEND M
WHERE DTFIMSEPARACAO IS NOT NULL
AND DATA>= SYSDATE-1
```

But then the PowerBI problem came, when trying to establish the connection as Oracle Server with the instruction above I get the error **Details: "This native database query isn't currently supported."**

I hope there is a way to get around with this and still use the SQL Instructions so I get a great advantage in manipulating the data that I'll work with PowerBI, thanks!

My PowerBI version is Version: 2.83.5894.881 64-bit (july de 2020)

Comment: I'm not sure, are you trying to use a function to convert from a number to time? Can you not cast it , or use to_date?

Comment: I tried without success, it returns ORA-00932 error inconsistent data type, expected TIME and returned DATE JULIAN when tried with CAST, cast worked converting from number to other types but not time.